# ASP MVC 4 Global DBContext caching of entities

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
//Check if NewsItems exists in HttpRuntime.Cache
...

//If it does not, add the items to cahce
using (var Work = new UnitOfWork())
{
    var NewsItems=Work.Repository<NewsRepository>().GetTop10();
    //Store NewsItems in HttpRuntime.Cache
    ...
}
```

After that, I use `NewsItems` from `HttpRuntime.Cache`. My problem is that sometimes `NewsItems` are still attached to the old context and I am not sure how to deattach them properly.

I've tried something simple like this:

```
foreach (var NewsItem in NewsItems) {
    Work.Context.Entry(NewsPost).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;    
}
```

But it doesn't seem to de-attach itself properly and I get exceptions of multiple contexts using same entity.

Should I clone the entity instead? Or should I be de-attaching my entities differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
foreach (var NewsItem in NewsItems)
{
    ((IObjectContextAdapter) Work.Context).ObjectContext.Detach(NewsItem);
}
```

Comment: I realized that it was a user error, I was trying to attach an object twice. But your alternative method should work as well.